# Creating instance variables in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a program that needs to handle sets of a bunch of associated variables. I want to bundle them all into a class so I can access them intuitively...

```
class transition():
...

t1 = transition(stuff_to_initialize)
retrieve_that_variable = t1.that_variable_in_initialized_stuff
```

but I'd like to be able to declare my instance variables from a for loop:

```
class transition(object):
    ''' instance of a transition includes...
    '''
    # order convention for uncertainty terms Cij
    __order = {'c11': 1, 'c22': 2, 'c33': 3, 'c12': 4, 'c13': 5, 'c23': 6}
    __vector = {'Rx': 0.0, 'Ry': 0.0, 'Rz': 0.0}


    def __init__(self, cij=__order, vector=__vector):
        # Things that a transition instance must specify
        self.layer_type = 0

        for item in cij.keys():
            self.item = 0           
        for item in vector.keys():
            self.item = 0
```

but in this example, after initializing an instance of `transition` I just have an instance variable `transition.item`.

Can I initialize instance variables from a list of variable names?

Comment: If I understand you, you want to name these things dynamically?  Why not just create a variable that holds a copy of the dictionaries you're using for reference?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, this is a [bad idea](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad way to go about it but the function you want is `setattr`. 
You can do

```
for item in cij.keys():
    setattr(self, item, 0)
```

So yes, you can initialize instance variables from a list of names. 
It's hard to see why you wouldn't just use a dictionary in this case though.

Comment: In my case I'm essentially replacing a human with a code to handle I/O for another simple program. At a later point I need to generate input files for a subprocess in a specific format , and in my mind being able to grab the relevant info from `t1 = transition()` ... `t1.value_I_need` makes the program less dependent on syntax... user input doesn't need specific keywords for parsing input, only for the class to be properly initialized.

On the other hand, I'm self taught so I could be doing things in a silly way.

Thanks for the response!

Comment: How is that different from `t1 = {}... t1['value_I_need']`? At some point in your programme the names of the attributes will have to be inputted and it's very hard to see why you wouldn't just store them as keys in a dictionary which maps them to the corresponding values.